# Conditional expectation conditionally on the sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$ generated by the Borel subsets of $[0,1/2]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and let $X(\omega)= \omega$. Find $\mathbb{E} \left(X|\mathcal{G}\right)$ if (a) $\mathcal{G} = \left\{ [0,1/2], (1/2, 1], [0,1], \emptyset \right\} $ and (b) $\mathcal{G}$ is generated by the family of sets $\left\{ B \subset[0,1/2], \text{Borel} \right\}$.

The first part is easy as there is only a finite number of atoms so that the conditional expectation is $\mathbb{E} (X| \mathcal{G}) = 1/4$ if $\omega \in [0,1/2]$ and $\mathbb{E} (X| \mathcal{G}) = 3/4$ for $\omega \in (1/2,1]$. I am having trouble, however, with the second part as I cannot visualize this sigma field. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Let $\mathcal C=\{B\in\mathbb B(\Omega)\mid B\subseteq[0,1/2]\}$, can you show that $\mathcal G=\sigma(\mathcal C)$ is $$\mathcal G=\mathcal C\cup\{B\cup(1/2,1]\mid B\in\mathcal C\}\ ?$$ As a consequence, $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable if and only if $Y$ is $\mathcal B(\Omega)$-measurable and $Y(\omega)=Y(\omega')$ for every $\omega$ and $\omega'$ in $(1/2,1]$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the hint. The first part of $\mathcal{G}$ is clear, the second follows from the need to include the complements?

Comment: Downvoting a question from someone who is trying to learn is not very constructive, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. How do you know who votes what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You are looking for a $\mathcal G$-measurable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with: $$\int_Axdx=\int_Af(x)dx\text{ for every }A\in\mathcal G$$

Note that in b) a function is $\mathcal G$-measurable iff it is Borel measurable and is constant on $(\frac12,1]$.

How about $f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ if $x\leq\frac12$ and $x\mapsto c$ otherwise, where $c$ denotes some (yet to be found) constant?

Comment: A function $f$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{G}$. How would making it a constant on $(1/2, 1]$ ensure this?

Comment: If $f$ is constant on $(\frac12,1]$ and takes value $c$ there then $f^{-1}(B)=A\cup C$ where $A$ is a Borel measurable subset of $[0,\frac12]$ and where $C\in\{\varnothing,(\frac12,1]\}$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: And by the way, the constant is $3/4$.

Comment: That is correct.